# When to use mmap over sysdef?

Tags: c++

I am developing an application, which has to call some HW registers.  There are many calls, called in random order.  The maps will be large, not sure if they will be a multiple of PAGE_SIZE though.

I was wondering what things I should consider when choosing mmap over sysdef,  So a system call.  Or any other method.

The app will be done in Linux and C++.

Comment: mmap on linux should only cost you for the pages you actually access, you can map a large amount of data but you should only have to 'pay for' the pages you access / modify.

Comment: What's "sysdef"? I don't think you're talking about the Unix command.